# Ошибка Inappropriate blocking method call при http запросе в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, coroutine

Изучаю корутины и возник вопрос. Набросал простую функцию для получения данных из сети. Но в Intelij IDEA выделяет желтым URL(url).openConnection() и выводит предупреждение "Inappropriate blocking method call"

Пробовал вызывать так

```
runBlocking { 
    getHttp("http://link.ru")
}
```

Ставил модификатор suspend для fun main - один фиг выделяет. В чем ошибка?

```
suspend fun getHttp(url: String): String {
    var txt = ""
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        with(URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection) {
            try {
                txt = inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
            } catch (e:Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
    return txt
}
```

Comment: Идея возможно не полностью разбирается в корутинах, вот пишет.

Comment: та нет. Насколько я понял, HttpUrlconnection вызывается блокирующе и может бросить исключение  в виде IOException. По ходу вся суть использования корутин тогда сходит на нет, но это не точно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы вызываете блокирующий HttpUrlConnection, и как правильно заметили в комментариях - вся суть использования корутин сходит на нет.

Решить данную проблему можно несколькими способами, либо использовав асинхронный клиент типа Retrofit, либо оборачивать блокирующий код в отдельный поток. По [ссылке](https://fox-code.ru/a/oshibka-inappropriate-blocking-method-call-kotlin/) статья с подробным объяснением и решением.